# How can my 3GB SD Card have 76GB files

Tags: storage

What are these files in SD Card /Android/data/com.android.chrome/ 
And these are only in SD Card. They were never there before today. And they total above 76GB, in the attached picture only one screenshot is shown. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]!

Comment: try to repair with *adb shell fsck_msdos -y /dev/block/mmcblk1p1* or make backup and format. the folder can be deleted

Comment: As alecxs already mentioned the size, the defect names and the strange dates indicates a defect file system.

Comment: Thanks for you guys help. I got injured so could not thank in time. I found out that the sd card was physically damaged, so I had to buy a new one anyway. But I will definitely try to repair file system, using the commands above. Thanks once again for helping.